# Is there a different between session -with mode sqlServer- and Profile

Tags: asp.net, session

Is there a different between **session -with mode sqlServer-** and **Profile** ? and who gives us best performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that there is a difference: SQLServer SessionState mode means that everything you put in the ASP.NET Session (not only user profile data) will get serialized and persisted in a SQL Server database, whereas the Profile could be persisted wherever you configure it to. There are out-of-the-box profile providers that persist the information in SQL Server. Definitely go with a profile. Don't use ASP.NET Sessions at all. The best ASP.NET SessionState mode is the following:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

I'd recommend you to always use it. It will make your web application stateless, the way they should be.

Comment: thank you, but why you encouraged me to make my web application stateless? what are the benefits from doing that?

Comment: Because the HTTP protocol is stateless. Stateless applications are more scalable. You simply throw hardware to your web farm and you get almost *free* performance boost.

Comment: Ok, do you encourage me to use profile when i'm using one server?

Comment: and what about performance issue? every page request will require additional sql server request and that will kill a website performance.. do you agree with me ?